# How to use if statements as ruby injections in html?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, code-injection

so what I started off trying to do was to perform an if statement within my html code where @events was defined in my controller:

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
       <% if event.starts_at.hour() == 9 %>
       <p> <%= event.name %>
       <% end %>
<% end %>
```

but obviously now after trying to load it, the program doesn't like this. (I am very new to ruby so I have to at least try these things out!)

The error I am given when trying this is:

C:/Users/Sarah/RubymineProjects/MyApp/app/views/calendars/_show.html.erb:49: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n' ...? && event.starts_at.hour ==9 );@output_buffer.safe_append=' ... ^ C:/Users/Sarah/RubymineProjects/MyApp/app/views/calendars/_show.html.erb:52: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' '.freeze; end ^ C:/Users/Sarah/RubymineProjects/MyApp/app/views/calendars/_show.html.erb:54: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' '.freeze; end ^ C:/Users/Sarah/RubymineProjects/MyApp/app/views/calendars/_show.html.erb:364: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')' C:/Users/Sarah/RubymineProjects/MyApp/app/views/calendars/_show.html.erb:366: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'

Why is this happening? Is it because my _show.html.erb is a partial being used in my main.html.erb? 
How would I go about doing this?

Here is an attempt I made with my Pages controller. The html file is called _show.html.erb which belongs to another controller, but it is rendered into the main.html.erb file belonging to the Pages controller.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  #before_action :require_customer, only: [:main]

  def home

  end


  def main
    @events = current_customer.calendar.events

    def mon900(event)
      if(event.day()==1 && event.hour()==9)
        @mon900 = event
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and I called this method in the html like this:

```
<% if @mon900 %>
    <p>do something</p>
<% end %>
```

Am I on the right track? I have only been learning Ruby for a week and so am obviously not familiar with the framework and syntax. 
Thanks!

Comment: How if doesn't like it (show us the error)? Why are you nesting `mon900` inside `main`? Ok, I have more context know, after reading your question a couple of times: If mon900 depends on event exclusively, define it inside event.rb (model). BTW, `day == 1` is not monday, but the 1st of the month.

Comment: I have updated my question. I am getting a very long syntax error when i try your if statement code. Is this because I am writing it in a partial rather than a view? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I would simply rewrite it to:

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
  <% if event.starts_at.monday? && event.starts_at.hour == 9 %>
    <p><%= event.name %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

That said, I don't think this is the prettiest code? If events starting during 9AM on Mondays are important to you, you want to create a scope for it, so you call it something like: `@events.monday_at_9.each do |event|` without the if conditions inside the loop (read more about scopes in http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: this throws me an error when using if statements in the code. I have update my full question

Comment: as in, I tried the suggested if statement you gave me and returned a massive error which is now in my question

Comment: @Sarahshuffle, the error says unexpected ")", but the code sample I provided has no right parenthesis.